# 【 Instagram API 】howt can I fetch media insights with business_discovery?

Tags: facebook, instagram-api

I would like to fetch each media insights at once. I try to fetch them with business_discovry but I haven't.
If you know some resolves, please teach me.

API URL I tried

```
17535554xxx?fields=business_discovery.username(NAME){media_count,media{insights{engagement}}}
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Please read documentation for supported fields.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "AWje-t3mED9fzU02LfP441"
  }
}
```

PERMISSION

```
email
read_insights
pages_show_list
ads_management
ads_read
business_management
instagram_basic
instagram_manage_insights
pages_read_engagement
public_profile
```